# Output html into a variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I know the basics of Javascript and Jquery. However, i need to output some html in a Javascript variable. Here's the code:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "{% for entry in craft.entries.find() %}","<a href='{{ entry.url }}'>{{ entry.title }}</a>","{% endfor %}"
    ];
    $( "#search-results-general" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
}
);
```

The code within this Javascript is Twig and some html. Because the CMS i'm using is Craft CMS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Output where? To the page? To the console?

Comment: What's the problem? What is the code doing/not doing?

Comment: Hi guys,

So the variable needs to output some html tags, like the <a href=''>, to the same page. 

The code will output in the div #search-results-general with help from an external .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig normally runs on the server (first), JavaScript normally runs on the client (later, once the page has been turned to html). Twig tags that have been added by JavaScript will not be run unless you are using a very strange setup.

You should probably take a different approach to the wider problem, or edit the question and explain the detail of your setup more if you are doing strange things with server-side jQuery or client side twig libraries.

In the context of a twig file, you may be able to do something like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    {% for entry in craft.entries.find() %}
      "<a href='{{ entry.url }}'>{{ entry.title }}</a>",
    {% endfor %}
  ];
  $("#search-results-general").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
);
</script>
```

The aim of this is to have the twig generate lines of javascript code. Note that you will probably need to fix XSS vulnerabilities in the above.

Comment: Thanks!

This got me a bit cleaner output. Twig is not the problem here, and works fine.

An variable in jQeury and / or Javascript, will not output html. Only as plain text. So if i want to output the <a href=''></a>, it will literally output <a href=''> in the html file.

Comment: Assuming you have html as plain text in your js variable, you can do `$("#containerId").append(htmlvar);`  eg `$("body").append(availableTags);` in your js